# apex:slds not loading for Community Guest user, throws unsupported stylesheet MIME type error

Tags: visualforce, community, slds, guest-user, critical-update

The LDS CSS is not being loaded by using apex:slds tag for Community Guest User.
It generates a link tag as below:

```
<link class="user" href="/Customer/slds/css/gx0YG61QwKo3viF0Mc1gTw/min/scoped/one:oneNamespace,force:sldsTokens,force:base,force:formFactorLarge/slds.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I tried loading this URL in the guest user's context which throws 404/not found

However, the same page loads the Lightning CSS using  tag for authenticated user both on community and internally in Salesforce

I have temporarily loaded the Lightning styles using a Static Resource.

I noticed this problem recently on Thursday.

I am wondering if this is due to some critical update from Salesforce as I can see that the Guest user permissions to objects were revoked in my Sandbox instance in a recent update as quoted below:

> Applied to this org’s sandbox communities on January 7, 2019. This
>   update removed standard and custom object access from guest users so
>   that they can no longer create, read, update, and delete Salesforce
>   records.